# Looping CSV Concat in Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have multiple folders each containing csvs. I am trying to concat the csvs in each subdirectory and then export it. At the end I would have same number of outputs as the folders. At the end I would like to have Folder1.csv, Folder2.csv, ...Folder99.csv etc. This is what

```
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



rootDir = 'D:/Data'
OutDirectory = 'D:/OutPut'
os.chdir(rootDir)

# The directory has folders as follows
# D:/Data/Folder1
# D:/Data/Folder2
# D:/Data/Folder3
# ....
# .....
# D:/Data/Folder99

# Each folders (Folder1, Folder2,..etc.) has many csvs.

frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootDir):
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None, na_values=['-999'], delim_whitespace= True, header = 0,  skiprows = 2)
        OutFile = '%s.csv' % OutputFname
        list_.append(df)
        frame = pd.concat(list_)

        df.to_csv(OutDirectory+OutFile, sep = ',', header= True)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
IOError: File file200150101.csv does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate dirname and filename for a full path to your files. Change this line like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dirname, filename) ,index_col=None, na_values=['-999'], delim_whitespace= True, header = 0, skiprows = 2)
```

**Edit:**
I don't know how pandas works because I never used it. But i think your problem is, that you defined everything you wanted to be done to the CSVs in the inner loop that loops over files only (at least the indentation looks that way - but that could also be a format problem that occured when you pasted your code here on SO).

I rewrote your code and fixed some things that I think might be the problem:

- First, I renamed your variables starting with big letters because,
  for me, it always looks weird to have vars with big starting letters.
- I moved your list variable to the outer loop because it should be
  reset every time you enter a new directory as you want all CSVs to be
  merged per *folder*.
- And finally, I fixed the indentation. In    python indentation tells
  the compiler which commands are in the inner    or outer loop.

My code now looks like this. You might have to change some things because I can't test it right now:

```
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



rootDir = 'D:/Data'
outDir = 'D:/OutPut'
os.chdir(rootDir)
dirs = os.listdir(rootDir)

frame = pd.DataFrame()
for dirname in dirs: 
  # the outer loop loops over directories! the actual directory is stored in dirname
  list = [] # collect csv data for every directory, not in general
  files = glob('%s/*.csv' % (dirname))
  for filename in files:
    # the inner loop loops over the files in the 'dirname' folder
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None, na_values=['-999'], delim_whitespace= True, header = 0,  skiprows = 2)
    # all csv data should be in 'list' now
    outFile = '%s.csv' % dirname # define the name for output csv
    list.append(df) # do that for every file
    # at this point, all files in the actual directory were processed

frame = pd.concat(list_) # and then merge CSVs
# ...actually not sure how pd.concat works, but i guess it does merge the data
frame.to_csv(os.path.join(outDir, outFile), sep = ',', header= True) # save the data
```

Comment: When I am manually executing code for a folder at a time it completes within a fairly short time, now it is taking quite a bit of time with the loop. It is also adding output line by line in each csv. I did not put in the calculations in the above code but there's some resampling involved.

Comment: have you tried to list the files that are processed by the loop with a `print (os.path.join(dirname, filename))` to check if the loop actually reaches them? if it does, it might be an issue with panda.

Comment: Yes, it is spitting outputs but its barely crawling, I had have only three outputs generated after multiple hours

Comment: I tested a treewalk on my pc with basically the same code you have minus the panda stuff (never worked with panda) and it worked flawlessly for me. Maybe your performance problem is caused by the panda code you have in your loop. Maybe try to gather the csv records first and concat them after the loops are done. I don't know panda but it  seems like `frame = pd.concat(_list)` runs over your collection of csv records over and over again as it gets bigger and bigger. Try to do that after your loop.

Comment: I rewrote your code and edited the code that I think should be (near) correct ;)